# How to place an item into a chest when using multiverse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Say I have a chest in a world on my server that isn't in my spawn world, and I would like to run a command from the console to put an item in it, the usual replaceitem command always throws the error that the position is not loaded.

How do I switch which world the console is running that command on, or how do I add a flag to the command to specify the world, or how do I otherwise place an item into a chest in a world other than the spawn world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the chest/chunk is loaded you can use **execute in**.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
/execute in minecraft:<your_other_world> run <your_command_here>
```

For example:

```
/execute in minecraft:world run summon creeper 10 70 10
```

Comment: IIRC it's possible to load chunks by teleporting Armor Stands there. If that also works across dimensions via `execute in`, it would be a good addition to the answer.